# Hibernate orm.xml named native query. HibernateException: Errors in named queries: Advertisement.xmlNativeQuery

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data

I want to put named native query in orm.xml and use this blog post as reference:

https://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/spring-framework/spring-data-jpa-tutorial-creating-database-queries-with-named-queries/

though when I run I got an

**HibernateException: Errors in named queries: Advertisement.xmlNativeQuery**

**Cannot get why is it not works?**

Here orm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<entity-mappings
        xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm_2_0.xsd"
        version="2.0">

    <named-native-query name="Advertisement.xmlNativeQuery"
            result-class="java.lang.String">
        <query>SELECT NATIVE_ID FROM ADVERTISEMENT</query>
    </named-native-query>

</entity-mappings>
```

method call in repository:

```
@Repository
public interface AdvertisementRepository  extends CrudRepository<Advertisement, Long> {
    @Query(nativeQuery = true)
    public Set<String> xmlNativeQuery();
...
}
```

Advertisement class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "advertisement")
public class Advertisement {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) 
    Long id;
    ...
    @NotNull
    /* The web catalog have Advertisement number */
    @Column(name="native_id", length=31)
    String nativeId;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting the result-class in your orm.xml to your.package.Advertisement ?

Comment: No. I not tried. I want to get string data from property. I cannot get any doc describing this ..